# USB port failed after too many errors

Tags: windows-xp, usb

I have a flaky USB device which I am stuck with.  Don't ask.

Anyways, in windows I get a bunch of Usb unrecognized device sometimes and then sometimes it just works.  I do have a 500 mA powered hub, so its not a power issue.

The problem isn't that I sometimes don't get it to recognize as this is part of an automated process and I don't care if it just fails and tries again next time, the thing windows seems to disable a usb port after too many errors occur on it.

Has anybody run into this problem?  Can you tell windows to just re-enable the port or prevent it from being disabled in the first place?  Rebooting doesn't seem to help.  You have to shut down and do a full power cycle.

I am running Windows XP

Answer (score 1):

In the Device Manager, try disabling the USB Root Hub device where the problematic device is connected then re-enable it again.  You will want to go to the View menu and select "Devices by Connection" so that it shows you which is the right one.